# PowerShell IISAdministration 1.1.0.0 Missing Commands

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to use the 1.1.0.0 version of the IISAdministration PowerShell Module.  I have it installed and in my current session.  However, the two methods (Remove-IISSiteBinding and New-IISSiteBinding) which are new to 1.1.0.0, are not listed and when I try to call them I get the 'The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...' .  Can someone point me to what I might be doing wrong.  Below is what I am seeing.

Server 2016, Powershell 5.1

When I open a brand new session and run:

```
import-module -Name IISAdministration -RequiredVersion 1.1.0.0
$mod = Get-Module -Name IISAdministration
$mod.Version
$mod.ExportedCmdlets | Format-Table
```

I get:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      1      0      0       

Key                                  Value                               
---                                  -----                               
Clear-IISCentralCertProvider         Clear-IISCentralCertProvider        
Clear-IISConfigCollection            Clear-IISConfigCollection           
Disable-IISCentralCertProvider       Disable-IISCentralCertProvider      
Disable-IISSharedConfig              Disable-IISSharedConfig             
Enable-IISCentralCertProvider        Enable-IISCentralCertProvider       
Enable-IISSharedConfig               Enable-IISSharedConfig              
Export-IISConfiguration              Export-IISConfiguration             
Get-IISAppPool                       Get-IISAppPool                      
Get-IISCentralCertProvider           Get-IISCentralCertProvider          
Get-IISConfigAttributeValue          Get-IISConfigAttributeValue         
Get-IISConfigCollection              Get-IISConfigCollection             
Get-IISConfigCollectionElement       Get-IISConfigCollectionElement      
Get-IISConfigElement                 Get-IISConfigElement                
Get-IISConfigSection                 Get-IISConfigSection                
Get-IISServerManager                 Get-IISServerManager                
Get-IISSharedConfig                  Get-IISSharedConfig                 
Get-IISSite                          Get-IISSite                         
New-IISConfigCollectionElement       New-IISConfigCollectionElement      
New-IISSite                          New-IISSite                         
Remove-IISConfigAttribute            Remove-IISConfigAttribute           
Remove-IISConfigCollectionElement    Remove-IISConfigCollectionElement   
Remove-IISConfigElement              Remove-IISConfigElement             
Remove-IISSite                       Remove-IISSite                      
Reset-IISServerManager               Reset-IISServerManager              
Set-IISCentralCertProvider           Set-IISCentralCertProvider          
Set-IISCentralCertProviderCredential Set-IISCentralCertProviderCredential
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue          Set-IISConfigAttributeValue         
Start-IISCommitDelay                 Start-IISCommitDelay                
Start-IISSite                        Start-IISSite                       
Stop-IISCommitDelay                  Stop-IISCommitDelay                 
Stop-IISSite                         Stop-IISSite
```

Answer (score 1):

[IISAdministration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets) PowerShell Cmdlets were not supported prior to IIS 10.0

Please check your iis version.

Comment: I am running IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 as stated above, and the version of IIS installed on the server would not have bearing on the commands that are available in a module, does it?

Comment: Using this command `Get-Command -Module 'IISAdministration'`, then check whether this module contains Remove-IISSiteBinding and New-IISSiteBinding.